# Spring auditing annotations don't work with azure-spring-boot-starter-cosmos

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I'm setting up Spring application that uses cosmos db. Everything works (I mean I'm able to save, update, remove etc.) until I tried to use auditing annotations such as `@CreatedDate`. As far as I understand [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-data-cosmos-readme?view=azure-java-stable) it should be possible after annotating my app with `@EnableCosmosAuditing`. My current output is exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.(...).model.PersistableEntity!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$getRequiredPersistentEntity$2(PersistentEntities.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:401)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.markAudited(IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.java:81)
    at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.ReactiveCosmosTemplate.prepareToPersistAndConvertToItemProperties(ReactiveCosmosTemplate.java:660)
    at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.ReactiveCosmosTemplate.insert(ReactiveCosmosTemplate.java:348)
    at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.ReactiveCosmosTemplate.insert(ReactiveCosmosTemplate.java:375)
    at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.support.SimpleReactiveCosmosRepository.save(SimpleReactiveCosmosRepository.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.save(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.save(Unknown Source)
```

Application:

```
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.EnableCosmosAuditing;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCosmosAuditing
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Entity:

```
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.Container;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.GeneratedValue;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.PartitionKey;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Container(containerName = "entity")
public class PersistableEntity {

  @Id @GeneratedValue private String id;
  @CreatedDate
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;
}
```

Repository:

```
import com.amerisave.newton.asset.server.model.PersistableEntity;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.ReactiveCosmosRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersistableEntityRepository
    extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<PersistableEntity, String> {}
```

Service:

```
public PersistableEntity createEntity(PersistableEntity pe) {
    Mono<PersistableEntity> peMono = entityRepository.save(pe);
    return peMono.block();
```